# JDBC Type Scroll Insensitive and Sensitive

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc, resultset

When going through Java JDBC ResultSet Types, there is two scroll type TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE and TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, which I understood. But when I go to practical implementation, I didn't see the effect. Below is the code :

```
package com.jdbc.resultsettypeandconcurrency;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DatabaseMetaData;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class TypeInSensitiveConcurUpdate {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Connection con = null;
        Statement stmt = null;

        try {
            System.out.println("loading the driver.....");
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
            System.out.println("Driver loaded");
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl", "user", "pass");
            if(con!=null) {
                System.out.println("Connected to database");

            } else {
                System.out.println("Could not Get Connection");
            }

            stmt = con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
            String query = "select COF_NAME, SUP_ID, PRICE, SALES, TOTAL from COFFEES";
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
            System.out.println();
            int cnt = 1;
            while(rs.next()) {
                System.out.print(rs.getString("COF_NAME")+", ");
                System.out.print(rs.getInt("SUP_ID")+", ");
                System.out.print(rs.getFloat("PRICE")+", ");
                System.out.print(rs.getInt("SALES")+", ");
                System.out.print(rs.getInt("TOTAL")+"\n");
                if(cnt == 2){
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(20 * 1000);/**LINE:39*/
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                cnt++;
            }
            System.out.println();

        } catch(ClassNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("ClassNotFoundException : Driver Class not found");
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());

        } catch(SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("SQL Error "+e.getMessage());
            System.out.println(e.getErrorCode());

        } finally {
            if(stmt!=null) {
               stmt.close();
            }
            if(con!=null) {
               con.close();
            }
            System.out.println("All Connection closed");
        }
    }
}
```

When program reaches at LINE 39, I update the DB from backend for a record. For TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE it does not show the updated record which it should do but for TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE does not doing the desired behavior. It must show the updated record but not showing. Can anyone tell why is it so ?

I read somewhere when googled(not Java doc or JLS) that ODBC thin driver, OCI driver support INSENSITIVE ResultSet object and not sensitive. Is it so? If yes why and which driver supports both? If no then where I am going wrong.

I went through the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40026644/which-jdbc-drivers-support-scroll-sensitive-insensitive-properly), but didn't point to my question. Any Suggestion will be appreciated.

EDIT: Added these lines to check the support

```
DatabaseMetaData meta = con.getMetaData();
System.out.println("{TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, CONCUR_UPDATABLE} -> "+
                meta.supportsResultSetConcurrency(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE));
System.out.println("{TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE, CONCUR_UPDATABLE} -> "+
                    meta.supportsResultSetConcurrency(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE));
System.out.println("{TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE, CONCUR_READ_ONLY} -> "+
                    meta.supportsResultSetConcurrency(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY));
```

Below is the result I got:

{TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, CONCUR_UPDATABLE} -> true

{TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE, CONCUR_UPDATABLE} -> true

{TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE, CONCUR_READ_ONLY} -> true

Comment: Have you verified if it was actually created as sensitive? Drivers can downgrade if necessary (and the combination of TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE with CONCUR_UPDATABLE is more likely to be not supported). Also try with auto-commit disabled (default is auto-commit enabled).

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I verified with different combination also such as (TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE, CONCUR_READ_ONLY) but no luck. Also tried auto commit false. Can you explain what it means 'Drivers can downgrade if necessary '.

Comment: I mean verify by checking the actual runtime sensitivity using `ResultSet.getType()`. JDBC drivers are allowed to downgrade the concurrency or type if they can't satisfy the requested concurrency and/or type.

Comment: Also make sure to inspect the relevant `DatabaseMetaData` methods for the actual offered sensitivity guarantees.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I checked the support through DatabaseMetaData and edited my post. You can check the result it showing true. Any further suggestion.

Comment: @MarmiteBomber As you go through my post, I said at LINE 39 when sleep occurs I manually update it from backend to check the sensitivity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As with other features that *doesn't work* you must read the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/jjdbc/resultset.html#GUID-8360DD85-DBCE-485A-9E22-F7B7A5904D63) before using them.

The important thing is the notion of the window

> The Oracle implementation of scroll-sensitive result sets involves the concept of a window, with a window size that is based on the fetch size. The window size affects how often rows are updated in the result set.

So to observe the change of every single row, you must set the *fetch size* to 1.

Note that it is not enought to set the fetch size for the *resultSet*, because the default fetch size is 10 and the change is valid only for the 11th and the subsequent rows.

Therefore the fetch size must be set on the `prepareStatement`:

```
 def stmt = con.prepareStatement("""select id, val from test
 where  id between ? and ?  order by id""", ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE)
 stmt.setFetchSize(1)
 // set bind variables and execute statement
```

Now on each call of `rs.next()` a new window is opened, which leads to an internal call of [`refreshRow`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/jjdbc/resultset.html#GUID-264DC004-D0F0-4BD4-935C-438FD46DB412)

which gets the current values from the database.

Note that this bahaviour is performed ony for `TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE` for `TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE` no  `refreshRow` is called, so you see the constant data
as of the initial query even is you switch the window. You may call `refreshRow` explicitely to see the same effect.

Technically the functionality is implemented using two cursors. The first one corresponds to the used query, only adding the ROWID column.

```
 select rowid as "__Oracle_JDBC_internal_ROWID__", id, val from test
 where  id between :1  and :2   order by id
```

The second cursor called on each window switch (i.e. for fetch size = 1 for each row fetched) simple outer joins the saved `rowid` with the query from the first cursor to refetch the current data.

```
WITH "__JDBC_ROWIDS__" AS (SELECT COLUMN_VALUE ID, ROWNUM NUM FROM TABLE(:1 ))
SELECT "__JDBC_ORIGINAL__".*
FROM (select rowid as "__Oracle_JDBC_internal_ROWID__", id, val from test
where  id between :2  and :3   order by id) "__JDBC_ORIGINAL__", "__JDBC_ROWIDS__"
WHERE "__JDBC_ORIGINAL__"."__Oracle_JDBC_internal_ROWID__"(+) = "__JDBC_ROWIDS__".ID
ORDER BY "__JDBC_ROWIDS__".NUM
```

There are similar question out there, but none of them realy explains the problem, so I do not mark this question as duplicated:

[Behaviour of ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091659/behaviour-of-resultset-type-scroll-sensitive/25585046)

[JDBC ResultSet Type_Scroll_Sensitive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19659268/jdbc-resultset-type-scroll-sensitive)

[JDBC result set type scroll sensitive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42622929/jdbc-result-set-type-scroll-sensitive/42626408#42626408)

The *short answer* is that the **default fetch size you used is to high to observe an update of a single row**.

The test were done on
`Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.2.0.1.0`
`DriverVersion 12.2.0.1.0`

Comment: Understood. this means we have to put refreshRow even for sensitive to detect updated data, and since jdbc supports refreshRow for {insensitive,updatable}, then it clearly shows there will be no difference between them if refreshRow is put in program.

Comment: Well either you calls `refreshRow` explicitely on demand (which is probably more meaningfull) or you set the *fetch size* to one and the call of `refreshRow` is done  *implicite* for you.

Comment: That's fine. What I am querying is putting _refreshRow_ either on demand or not and then put any of the _ResultSet_ type either _{insensitive,updatable}_ or _{sensitive,updatable}_ will behave in same way.

Comment: @Nizam not sure about your formulation, but I'd recommend to set the cursor `TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE` and call the `refreshRow` on demand. You have a full controll of the re-reading the updated data and you can use a meaningfull *fetch size*.